# Determine if a DocuSign account exists using accountName

Tags: docusignapi

Is there any way to locate a DocuSign account using the accountName property (and not the account Id)?  The REST API only has a method to get account info by Id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can not get account info based on the account name, only the accountId.  The accountId is part of the URL that you use in the REST request and the equivalent does not exist for account names unfortunately.  If you want to do it by account name what you can do is create a simple lookup table that links account names to account Ids, and based on the account name use its corresponding accountId for the request.

For reference, [this is the request that is currently supported](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Get%20Account%20Information.htm)